# Persisting Form data while adding additional copies of a <div> to the form

Tags: javascript, ajax, spring, jsp, dojo

I am working on SpringMVC Webapp. I have a view which consists of a dynamic form. The dynamic elements of the form are shown in the below:

Now, the current scenario is:

I pass the variable `${worksiteCount}` from my controller to the view (stored in my portlet session - defaulted to 1).

The form submit consists of a @ActionMapping that handles form data at the backend.
I have another Button in my page which allows the user to add additional engineering worksites if necessary - Additional Worksite #1 etc).

The click triggers a @RequestMapping that updates "worksiteCount" and returns the view with the additional form fields.

The issue with this is: Whatever data I have filled in the form gets deleted on click of this request.

How do I persist this data within the session? For example, should I use an Ajax Script (using DOJO/Vanilla JS preferably) to increase the variable {worksiteCount} asynchronously on the jsp side?

If so, how do I do it without refreshing the view?
I am a beginner in Ajax-Dojo(like the dojo.xhrGet/post), Spring framework. Kindly help.

```
<c:if test="${worksiteCount>1}">
            <c:set var="i" value="0"/>
            <c:forEach var="worksiteAddresses" items="${worksiteAddresses}"> 
            <c:set var="i" value="${i+1}"/>

                <c:if test="${worksiteCount>1}">
                <div class="row">
                <h2 id="worksiteAddress${i}" name="worksiteAddress${i}">Additional Worksite<span>${i}</span></h2>
                </div>
                </c:if>

             <div class="row">
                <div id="f-addr1" class="field">
                    <label>Address1<span><tag:requiredIcon/> </span></label>
                    <input class="" type="text" value="${worksiteAddresses.companyAddressLine1}" id="addressLine1${i}" name="addressLine1${i}" onblur="validateControl('addressLine1${i}');"/>
                </div>
                <div id="f-addr2" class="field">
                    <label>Address2</label>
                    <input class="" type="text" value="${worksiteAddresses.companyAddressLine2}" id="addressLine2${i}" name="addressLine2${i}" />
                </div>              
                <br class="clear" />
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div id="f-city" class="field">
                    <label>City<span><tag:requiredIcon/> </span></label>
                    <input class="" type="text" name="city${i}" id="city${i}" value="${worksiteAddresses.companyCity}" onblur="validateControl('city${i}');" />
                </div>
                <div id="f-zip" class="field">
                    <label>Zip<span><tag:requiredIcon/> </span></label>
                    <input class="" type="text" name="zip${i}" id="zip${i}" value="${worksiteAddresses.Zipcode}" onblur="validateZipControl('zip${i}',${i});" />
                </div>
                <br class="clear" />
            </div>

            </c:forEach>
        </c:if>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding this correctly and the ONLY effect of hitting the button on the page that updates the form with new fields for Additional Worksites there are several ways to handle that. The simplest might be:

1) Have the fields already ON the page, but hidden and use JS to make them visible. This way the existing form data is already preserved.

If some data needs to be pulled from the server side using existing data and changes somewhat the nature of the data already ON the form, then that really is a Submit and should be handled by the controller as such.

2) Either you can return all the original data modified however with new fields as well, or use AJAX to just get the NEW data in combination with answer #1.